# How to create sensible error plots in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Not sure if what i'm trying to do makes sense. I am prototyping some code in mathematica, I one day hope to write in C++. An environment in which I only can compute in double precision (as I'm using the MS VC++ compiler).

I have a polynomial which approximates a function f and I want to plot the error curve. The coefficients of the polynomial have been computed to machine precision (as would be the case in C++). But when I plot the relative error I just obtain a plot of numerical noise. I would expect the error to be a smooth curve since the polynomial is a Taylor polynomial. How can I obtain a more sensible plot? The code below demonstrates what I am trying to do, with the Cos function as a test case. The result of the plot is just numerical noise.

```
f[x_] = Cos[x]
a[k_] := N[(-1)^k/(2*k)!]
approx[x_] := Sum[a[k]*x^(2*k), {k, 0, 12}]
Plot[approx[x]/f[x] - 1, {x, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

I could increase the precision in which the coefficients `a[k]` are calculated.

```
a[k_] := N[(-1)^k/(2*k)!,30]
```

to obtain a more sensible plot but this defeats the purpose of my prototype code. Because eventually I want to graph the error plots of the approximants which I create in C++. And in that environment the coefficients will only be computed in double precision.

I think this test makes sense?? I expect my approximation to be accurate to about machine precision, but how can I plot the error curve?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, plotting `approx[x]/Cos[x] - 1` over a range that includes either `Pi/2` or `-Pi/2` is only going to cause problems as `Cos[x]` goes to zero at those points. At those points, `approx` is very nearly zero, but not exactly so. Also, `Cos[x]` is evaluated algebraically to be zero prior to being converted to a numerical zero when dividing, so you see spikes at those points.

Second, when plotting over a more sensible region,

```
Plot[approx[x]/f[x] - 1, {x, 0, 0.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get

[image]

which is exactly what I expect when operating near machine precision. Each spike is roughly equivalent to a single bit.

Lastly, if you want a good approximation across the entire domain of interest, I would not use a Taylor expansion which is good only in a neighborhood around the point of expansion. Instead, I would look at a [min-max approximation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0j4z3j4b-ike) using [Chebyshev polynomials](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChebyshevT.html). For instance, taking the Chebyshev series and the Taylor series out to 14 terms gives

[image]

where I'm plotting the absolute difference between each series and `Cos`. As you can see from the plot on the left, the Chebyshev series performs much better overall than the Taylor series on the right.